# Expo Go launch preview build only

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

I have been developing my app for quite a while and had some minor issues with Expo Go not working sometimes, but for the most part it has been working fine. Until a few days ago when i experienced the same issue as listed here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26591
I had errors pop up in the Expo Go client. I tried creating a preview build to see if it was only an issue in Expo Go, which it wasn't because my app crashed. At least I think this is why my app crashed, but that's irrelevant.
After creating the preview build I could no longer get Expo Go to open my app as an Expo Go app. It would only open my installed preview build apk. I tried uninstalling the preview build, and when scanning the Metro QR code nothing happened. Only a quick screen flash. When I reinstalled the preview build apk the code would open the preview build again. Then I tried building another preview build which seems to work fine, but it will only open the newly built apk or whatever preview build I install.

I have tried reinstalling Expo Go, deleting node_modules and .expo files. Nothing seems to change what is happening. When reverting my code to a previous branch and launching via the QR code i get an instant Expo Error blue screen with error log saying: manifest string is not a valid json object expo, and output is an HTML document.

Comment: The expo url is exp+myapp://expo-development-client/?url=http...